# Cant receive Firebase Cloud Message (without notification) on ios in foreground in unity game

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a game on android and ios and use firebase cloud messages with firebase functions to implement in app messaging between users. I receive those messages in unity through OnMessageReceived callback and everything works as intended on Android, but not on ios.
Here is my code sample on backend, when I send message through Firebase Messaging in Functions:

`

```
const message={
    data:{
        code:code.toString(),
        data:undefined
    }
}
if(data!=null)
{
    if(typeof data !=='string')
    {
        data=JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    message.data.data=data;
}
await messaging.sendToDevice(tokens,message).
catch((err:any)=>{
    error(err);
    return -1;
});`
```

And here is code sample from client app, where I register for incoming messages and retrieve a device token, which I then send via function to database:

```
        public void Init()
    {
        FirebaseMessaging.TokenRegistrationOnInitEnabled = true;
        FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
        FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    }
    void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        GCMcallback?.Invoke(e.Message.Data);
    }
    public void TurnGcmOff()
     {
         FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived -= OnMessageReceived;
         FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived -= OnTokenReceived;
         gcmToken = null;
     }
    public async UniTaskVoid CheckGCMActivity()
    {
        if (!subscribed)
        {
            Debug.Log("Gcm activity is down. Re-subscribing");
            await SubscribeToGCM();
        }
    }
    public async UniTask SubscribeToGCM()
    {
        if(subscribed)
            return;
        subscribed = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gcmToken))
        {
            await SendGCMToken();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tokenGetRetries; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Getting token async");
            var token =await FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && token != "StubToken")
            {
                Debug.Log($"Token received: {gcmToken}");
                gcmToken = token;
            }
            //Debug.Log($"token loaded: {token}");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gcmToken)&&gcmToken != "StubToken")
            {
                TokenReceivedCallback?.Invoke(gcmToken);
                await SendGCMToken();
                return;
            }
            await UniTask.Delay(1000);
        }
        Debug.LogWarning("Not able to get token!");
        
    }
```

OnMessageReceived callback doesnt fire on ios no matter what I do. Device token is actually generated on ios device and sent to database. APNS is uploaded to firebase console and Push Notifications capabilities added in XCode. I am actually able to receive background push notifications in ios, but not regular data messages in foreground. Just like Apple do not delivers these messages, if I do not include "notification" field in message payload. And I do not want to use push notifications overall, only custom data messages in foreground, which works perfect on android.
My Firebase Unity SDK version is 10.0.1, Unity version 2020.3.43.f1 and target OS level is iOS 13

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general, questions should include the code you've attempted along with troubleshooting steps and an indication of which line is failing. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Updated the question to include code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve the problem. Seems that

```
await messaging.sendToDevice(tokens,message)
```

was actually deprecated method, which still worked with android messages and notifications, and also with ios push notifications, but not with ios foreground messages. Documentation lacked this clarification, so it was purely luck finding out the issue. So I now use either

```
messaging.send(messageData) or messaging.sendMulticast(messageData)
```

and everything work as expected. Note that in these new methods token should be included in message data like this

```
const message: TokenMessage = {
    data: {
        "your message data"
    },
    token
}
```

Hope that helps if someone faces this problem